# Entity Framework Many-to-Many Clustered vs. Nonclustered Index

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I designed an entity data model with two entities between which there exists a many to many relationship. When I auto-generate SQL code to generate the database for this model, it has generated a table (two columns) to keep track of this many-to-many association. However, this table has a PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED on both columns.

Since I want this to work on SQL Azure which doesn't like tables with only nonclustered indices, I was wondering whether there is a good way of telling the code generation to generate clustered indices? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try giving it a surrogate key?

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  I realise this is an old question but doesn't seem to have been answered.  Azure still doesn't support Nonclustered keys which EF generate.

Answer (score 3):

I have another file called Model.indexes.sql that contains scripts to create additional indexes beyond the basic ones EF generates, such as those for performance optimizations.

Although this is not ideal, I added into this an index drop and create for each EF association to convert the Non-Clustered indexes into indexed ones:

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyAssociation]
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyAssociation]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyAssociation]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyAssociation]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Table1_Id], [Table2_Id] ASC);
GO

This is executed after every "Generate Database from Model...". I would love a more elegant solution.