# Code First Migrations in SQL Azure - Tables without a clustered index are not supported

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I can't seem to get my Code-First Migration to create my SQL Azure database.

It keeps complaining about SQL Azure's lack of support for tables without clustered indexes and I cant find a way around to create my database.

**Note:** I'm using `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` to create the change tracking tables on the first time database creation because apparently `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` [doesn't do that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8630863/1267778)

```
    public partial class IUnityDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public IUnityDbContext()
            : base("Name=IUnityDbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<IUnityDbContext>()); 
            //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<IUnityDbContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }




    public partial class Initial : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Users",
                c => new {
                        ... 
                     }
            ).PrimaryKey(u => u.UserId, clustered: true);            
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.Users");
        }
    }
```

If I try to `Update-Database I get

```
 Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
```

The database is not created.

**UPDATE:** I started from scratch and followed [this guide](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2012/11/13/enable-automatic-code-first-migrations-on-sql-database-in-azure.aspx) to enable Automatic Migrations (scratched the database and started with a non-existing one so I didn't have to remove the Up/Down code from the Initial migration)

This time my database was successfully created (Did not get this far before) but the tables are not created and I still get the same error as before about no support for tables without clustered indexes.

Please advise

Comment: Does all the code look correct which why nobody has answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out to be a bug in Entity Framework 6 -Alpha 3. I guess I should've mentioned that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282861/1267778

Answer (score 2):

This one looks similar (although it's not the ideal solution imho): [Entity Framework Many-to-Many Clustered vs. Nonclustered Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567946/entity-framework-many-to-many-clustered-vs-nonclustered-index)

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure how it applies. I'm using Code-First not Model-First and the migration fails to even create the database so I don't know at which step I should be altering the table.

Comment: And besides, my migration has the line to make the primary key clustered

Comment: Updated my question. I started from scratch using Automatic Migrations and was able to get the database created but not the tables (getting the same error). I set the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer in the DbContext constructor. At which step (and how) can I inject an sql statement to fix the issue?