# Updating database keys, clustered index error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with VS2013 on an asp.net web api project an Entity Framework deployed on Azure

I'm trying to alter the keys on one of my tables to instead of being composed of 2 foreign keys its composed of 3 keys. Using the `Add-Migration` command it generates the following migration

```
public partial class ChangeKeys_v4 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "ClientId", "Order", "ZoneId" });
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "ClientId", "ZoneId" });
    }
}
```

This is the entity class that was changed to include order as a key:

```
public class MyTable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Order { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3), ForeignKey("Zone")]
    public string ZoneId { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }

    public MyTable() { }
    public MyTable(Client c, int o, Zone z)
    {
        Client = c;
        Order = o;
        Zone = z;
    }
}
```

I've successfully did `Update-Database` on my development environment, but when doing so to the text environment I get the following error

```
Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated.
```

What changes can I do to my migation class so it works.

I've seen some solution and most say to drop table, and that's not really an option for when I have to push to production environment.

Comment: Is the production environment on Azure?

Comment: yes all the environments are on Azure

Comment: You might found this useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354953/code-first-migrations-in-sql-azure-tables-without-a-clustered-index-are-not-su

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the EF code->DB upgrade for this change with Azure hosting the db.

First, you have to have downtime. Then you run a script in SSMS connecti ng to the Azure DB. The script will:

1. Renames MyTable to e.g. TableOld
2. Creates MyTable with the new PK, FK's etc
3. insert into MyTable(col names) select (col names) from MyTableOld;
4. Run some checks: row counts in both tables, other queries which you know the results to. Basically check everything works.
5. Drop table MyTableOld

Maybe delay step 5 until you're sure it's all OK after the users have given it a test drive.

Comment: i was looking the database servers and the development env i was able to apply the script and this is enabled `LATEST SQL DATABASE UPDATE (V12)` on the server but on the other servers I have `Try Latest SQL Database Update (V12)`. If i activate V12 will it probably accept the operation like development sense the error is `Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server`

Comment: That sounds like your answer then!

Comment: well i ended up trying your solution and it worked :) tks